# Web Scraping & Csv making

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am doing a project that I am a little stuck on. I am trying to web scrape a website, to grab all of the cast and its characters.

I successfully grab the cast and characters from the wiki page and I get it to print out their personal wikipedia pages.

My question is, is it possible to make a program that produces the wiki by using a loop?

Next, I would want to use the loop to scrape each `actors/actresses` from their personal wikipedia page to scrape their age and they are from?

After the full code works and outputs what I have asked I need help by creating a csv file to make it print into the created csv file.

Thanks in advance.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_%26_Order:_Special_Victims_Unit'
html = urlopen(url) 
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

The above code imports the libraries I am going to use and has the `url` I am trying to scrape:

```
right_table=bs.find('table', class_='wikitable plainrowheaders')
table_rows = right_table.find_all('td')
for row in table_rows:
    try:
        if row.a['href'].startswith('/wiki'):       
            print(row.get_text())
            print(row.a['href'])
            print('-------------------------')

    except TypeError:
        pass
```

This is before I added the below print statements, I think there is a way to create a list that then creates a loop to grab where it prints `"/wiki/...."`

```
right_table=bs.find('table', class_='wikitable plainrowheaders')
table_rows = right_table.find_all('td')
    for row in table_rows:
        try:
            if row.a['href'].startswith('/wiki'):       
                print(row.get_text())
                link = ('https://en.wikipedia.org/'+ row.a['href'])
                print(link)
                print('-------------------------')

            except TypeError:
                pass
```

The above code currently prints the Cast and their allocated wikipedia page but I am unsure if thats the write way to do it. I am also printing my outcomes first before putting it all in the `CSV` to check and make sure I am printing out the right code

```
def age_finder(url):
        ...

        return age
```

The code above I am unsure what to put in where the `"..."` is to help return the age

```
for url in url_list:
        age_finder(url)
```

Comment: you can use this to het age from their pages if their age is available `bs.select('table.infobox.biography.vcard span.noprint.ForceAgeToShow') `. Of course you need to do some strip to get integer.